# How to disable particular days in date picker using angular, I used bsDatepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a working angular project and I used bsDatepicker **date picker** using by **text** type input, I need to disable **Saturday** and **Sunday** in the **date picker**.

Is possible to disable particular days?

```
            <input                  
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              #dp="bsDatepicker"
              bsDatepicker
              formControlName="delivery_date"
              placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"                 
              [minDate]="cartItems.minDeliveryDate"
              [isOpen]="isCalendarOpen"
              [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
            />
```

I need this kind of output

[image]

Comment: Not sure which date picker you are using, but it should probably have an NPM page that links to its docs.

Comment: @FrankFajardo i am using bsDatepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
bsDaterangepicker [daysDisabled]="[6,0]"
```